# Angular ui-router equivalent to reload $route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making the transition from NgRoute to ui-router using angular 1.0.8. Due to the fact I had some nested views I had to reload the routes which worked fine with ngRoute. I'm having the same issue with ui-router, is there an equivalent method I can use for this at all?

I'm using ui-router 0.2.10.

Edit:

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/4ZeXa/1/) to illustrate the issue that I'm having loading a basic view using ui-router.The view is requested and I can see it in the network inspector. The thing I can get my head around is why the view in not being injected into the template.

What am I missing here?

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```

Comment: I don't think I get what you're saying.  What do you mean reload the route?  Do you need to reload?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is `$state.reload()` which reloads the controller and the state.

Comment: Try: `$scope.enterState = function(stateID) { 
            $state.transitionTo(stateID);
        };
                                   $scope.enterState('one');
                                                $scope.$state = $state;`

Comment: Jayram, where do I put this call?

Comment: Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `reload()` function:

```
$state.reload()
```

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

You would put this in a controller like so:

```
var app angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.reload = function(){
        $state.reload();
    }
});
```

**Edit 1**

This is wrong.

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```

You just need to inject `$state` into the controller you want to use it in.

```
angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope,$state)
    // Use $state here
    $state.go('stateName');
{}]);
```

Comment: Hi Sam, I've put this into my fiddle and also tested it in my application, the reload works fine and I can see the view being requested. It's just not loading into the page. What am I missing? I've posted a fiddle.

Comment: Hi @Sam, I'm not sure how to implement the solution you are proposing. Are you able show me in the fiddle I've created? My controller loads a template, then I want to load the views into that.

Comment: Hi @Sam, I don't see any difference. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In your app module, you have `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency, you need `ui.router`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject ui.router, do that and it works fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/Christian_Schiffer/wLybswL9/1/

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
    $stateProvider.state('one', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/one.html',
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}).run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});

myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/mobileTemplate.html';
});

myapp.controller('AccordionDemo', function ($scope) {
    $scope.groups = [{
        title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
        routePath: "one.html",
        number: 1,
        current: true
    }, {
        title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
        routePath: "two.html",
        number: 2,
        current: false
    }];
});
```